# Why is the "harden" suite of packages not available for Debian Jessie (8.0)?

Tags: debian, hardening

These include all the **harden packages** listed in the Debian automatic hardening documentation (https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch-automatic-harden.en.html), including:

- *harden*
- *harden-tools*
- *harden-servers*
- *harden-clients*
- *etc., etc.*

Confusingly, it appears that the suite's [*documentation* package](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=harden-doc) will be available for **Debian Stretch (9.0)**, but none of the harden meta-packages are currently slated for that release either.

What gives? Are there alternative replacement packages that I overlooked? If so, what are they?

---

*It may be worth noting that I spent a great deal of time searching for the answer to this question online. There seems to be no information on this topic, and I've found nothing in the mailing lists, though I haven't search as thoroughly there.*

*All I have found is that the packages must have been available for Jessie at some point, but were later removed, as some Google queries still return dead links to Jessie package information pages.*

*The harden packages were a novice administrator's godsend, though I understand they were never the complete answer to securing a Debian server. Still, it is odd not seeing any explanation for their exclusion in Debian's newest releases.*

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So looking through the [bugs for harden](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?ordering=age;archive=both;package=harden) I found the following two bugs.

- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=782978

  - > Subject: RM: harden -- RoQA; no longer useful
    >   Date: Sun, 19 Apr 2015 20:12:06 -0400
    >   The maintainer thinks it would be best for it to be removed:
- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=760449

  - > Hi
    >   I agree with you. I think we should consider to remove the package
    >   altogether.
    >   // Ola

So the answer seems to be that the maintainer didn't think it was useful or functional anymore.

I have never used the package, so I can't provide much beyond linking you to the correct bug reports.

Comment: Wow, interesting. I guess I never thought to search the bug reports. Still, I wonder why it was considered best to remove the package altogether rather than update it. Removing it certainly makes rudimentary hardening harder (no pun intended) for novice admins. Is there a list which indicates what packages each of the harden members conflicted with? https://packages.debian.org/ doesn't detail package conflicts. Thanks for the answer!